# Using htaccess to force a directory to use HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to use .htaccess files to force a particular directory to use https. I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule roster/([\ A-Za-z]+)/$ roster/roster.php?s=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} members [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The first rewrite rule works, but the second doesn't do anything. I'm on Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat), if that helps.

Comment: you can always turn on mod_rewrite debug logging to see what's going on under the hood: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: I don't have that level of server access. I can only access my folders, which is why I'm doing the redirect in the .htaccess file